# Area under the curve in smaller and uniform intervals?

Tags: curve-fitting

I have 5 million individuals falling into 30 odd intervals, something like the below:

0: 9000
1-49: 8525
50-99: 7593
100-199: 7385
200-299: 4242
...

I would like to approximate the number of individuals in smaller and uniform intervals:

0
0-9
10-19
20-29
...

My layman idea is to exclude 0 and try to fit one or two curves to the rest of the data.

1. What methodological options do I have?
2. How do I go about in practice? Examples from python or other environment appreciated.
3. How do I ensure that the resulting area is close to the original 5 000 000 individual? (Is there a way to keep this constant and tweak the curve parameters?)

Comment: Your description of the data looks something like histogram bins. My suggestion is fitting the data to some as-yet-unknown statistical distribution, however finding that distribution will be time-consuming with millions of data points. Consider working with a smaller data subset, say every 1,000th point, while you search for a candidate statistical distribution. I have an online open source statistical distribution fitter that fits data to over 80 statistical distributions and ranks the results at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ though it is limited to 5,000 data points.

Comment: Can you add a plot of your histogram in your question?